# Dividing large number by 10 in python gives the wrong result

Tags: python, division

Say I want to remove the last digit of a number `n`.
For that I use the code `int(n/10)`.

Sadly this gives the wrong result for large numbers.
For example `n = 4474630975855204960` divided by `10` gives `447463097585520512`.

What's the reason for this behavior? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to multiply by 0.1, for large numbers perhaps is better to use some libraries that are more accurate.

Comment: The `/` operator returns a float value which is imprecise. Use `//` instead.

Comment: Use integer division.  `4474630975855204960 // 10`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: use integer division directly: `n//10`.

Comment: @JohnGordon @Julien Integer division with `//` instead of `/` does not work for this.

Comment: It works with the stated example of 4474630975855204960.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ok I tried `print("%.1f" % (n//10))` and it didn't work. `print(n//10)` does work.

Comment: You could use the `decimal` module. `decimal.Decimal("4474630975855204960").rotate(-1)`

Comment: `%.1f` is floating point format, so you have the same original problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some math operations, the Python interpreter will handle long integers for you and you don't have to think about it.

Division is different and converts integers to floats, which aren't handled well in Python.

You can get around this by directly using integer division - two // rather than just one /.

**Input**

```
4474630975855204960//10
```

**Output**

```
447463097585520496
```

Comment: No language handles floats any better; they are a fixed-precision approximation of real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax varies across python versions, use `//` to get integer division

```
$ python2 -c 'print("%d" % (4474630975855204960/10))'  # Integer division
447463097585520496
$ python3 -c 'print("%d" % (4474630975855204960/10))'  # Float division
447463097585520512
$ python3 -c 'print("%d" % (4474630975855204960//10))'  # True division
447463097585520496
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from `int`  to `str`, remove the last character, and convert it back to an `int`:

```
n = 4474630975855204960

print(int(str(n)[:-1]))
```

Output:

```
447463097585520496
```

Comment: That's a good solution to my problem, but it does not answer why the division is wrong.

Comment: @NicoG. Oh, sorry. I'm sure that the link below your post covers it though :)

Comment: This is 10x slower than simply dividing by 10 and harder to read.